# Archiving with Apple Mail and Gmail

Tags: email, gmail, apple-mail, archiving

What is the best way of archiving my messages in Apple mail so that it will be archived in Gmail as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using this AppleScript for about a year now, and it works great.

http://daringfireball.net/2007/07/simple_inbox_sweeper

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of Mail.app, delete or moving the email to the 'All Mail' mailbox would achieve this.

In Mail.app 7.3 (OS X Mavericks 10.9) Apple have made Mail.app a bit more Gmail friendly, and the standard Archive action now archives appropriately for Gmail.

Note that you *must* have the 'All Mail' mailbox enabled in IMAP from Gmail's settings for this to work in Mail.app in Mavericks.